# How can I assign JSON objects to attributes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have weather forecast saved in JSON format. I am trying to assign different objects to my specific attributes. How can I do that, when the JSON objects duplicate (there are many different dates under "date" object).
How can I assign the different dates to my attributes. For example day1: date[0]. And so on?

With current weather it works because there is only one date. (and all objects are there only once, whereas for 7 days forecast same data duplicates 7 times.)

```
var data = {
    "ConditionMatched": "Yes",
    "ConditionMatchedNum": "1",
    "ForecastWeather": {
      "Days": [{
        "date": "13/07/2019",
        "sunrise_time": "05:14",
        "sunset_time": "21:07",
        "slp_in": 30.06
      }]
    },

    const getCurrentWeatherJSON = (data) => {
      const temperatureText = `Teplota je ${data.date}°C.`;

      return {

        set_attributes: {
          weatherDescription: data.date[0],
          weatherFeelsLikeTempC: data.sunrise_time
        },
        messages: [{
            text: temperatureText
          },

        ]
      }
    };
```

Comment: `, const` is a syntax error. There is no JSON in your code.

Comment: This is part of designing your application. You have to decide what you want to do with multiple days of data.

Comment: But how can I assign each date to different attribute? When each date is saved in the same object "date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are really dealing with a JS object vs a JSON string.  If data is a JSON string then you need to parse it into an object:

```
const getCurrentWeatherJSON = (dataString) => {
  var data = JSON.parse(dataString);  // need to wrap in a try/catch for validation
```

Second, you are accessing the structure incorrectly.  The dates are under a member called ForecastWeather which has a child member called Days that is an array of objects.  If you can assume that Days is always going to have only 1 element, then you can access the date and sunrise time like this:

```
      weatherDescription: data.ForecastWeather.Days[0].date,
      weatherFeelsLikeTempC: data.ForecastWeather.Days[0].sunrise_time
```

although I have to say that your names don't seem to match the data in either of those two cases (why would weatherFeelsLikeTempC appropriately describe a time of day???).

Comment: It worked. I actually did not have to parse it. I was just incorrectly accessing the structure. Thank you!